# Session variable gone after redirect on localhost only using Drupal

Tags: php, redirect, drupal, cookies, session-variables

This seems to be a pretty popular question, however I have not been able to resolve my issue with any of the suggested solutions online. What's going on is, I am trying to set up a site locally that is already deployed on a server and working fine. Aside from changing the

```
$config['cookie_path'] = "/";
```

and the cookie_secure to false, I haven't changed much else.

The problem I am having is that the variable I am storing in $_SESSION doesn't seem to stick after redirecting to the main page. The workflow is:

1. Create a session, store session cookie in a table (this works fine, I can see it in the DB)
2. Store this var, which is passed in the URL to $_SESSION, you can echo it after the fact and it's there, just not after the redirect
3. Redirect to main page, get the previously stored var for other stuff

I have something like this:

in auth.php

```
    ....
    $this->session_var->store_var($var);
    // redirect to drupal homepage
    header('Location: /');
    exit;
```

in session_var.php

```
public function store_var($var)
    {       
        $_SESSION[$this->key] = $var;
    }
```

And once it redirects, I've printed throughout the workflow to check the $_SESSION and it's no longer there. Where this functions fine in multiple servers, I think this is probably a configuration issue, right??

I just don't know what other configurations to look at.

session.save_path has no value, after looking at phpinfo locally nor in any of the servers. So how is the session being saved?

cookie_domain is empty, cookie path is '/', httponly is false

If I can provide any other information, I'd be happy to. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: check `session_id()`. if the value changes between the pages, then you're most likely getting DIFFERENT sessions for each page.

Comment: @MarcB thanks for this suggestion. They are different. Would that because of session_start being called twice?

Comment: no. if you do `session_start(); session_start()`, nothing'll happen. most likely what IS happening is that your session cookie settings are incorrect, preventing your browser from sending page A's session cookie when page B is requested, and vice versa.

Comment: I'm looking through the configuration and nothing stands out to me. Is there something obvious that should be changed between deploying on the server vs my local machine that isn't $config['cookie_prefix'] = "";
$config['cookie_domain'] = "";
$config['cookie_path']  = "/";
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;

Comment: @jackie the `$config[]` vars...are they in your Drupal install in settings.php? If so they should be `$conf[]`. Just in case it's that simple

Comment: @Clive The stuff i commented on are in ci-engine\application\config\config.php. In settings.php, there is a a line $cookie_domain = ''; and the lifetime stuff is set, but not much else.

Comment: Ah ok, thought I'd mention it in case the problem was with Drupal's settings. Doesn't look like it is

Comment: Does anyone have any other idea why this would be happening?